Can autologin be set for Ubuntu Mate 24.04?
I maybe confused by what autologin is.
gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt

This does not work.I would like it to go straight to my desktop.
Can it be done?

That's for the TTY. You should configure LightDM for the GUI

This question is similar to: How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is not advisable if others have access to your computer.
sudo gpasswd --add andy nopasswdlogin

